# How cin works if user accidentally gives incorrect datatype?

Tags: c++, user-input, cin

I am new to C++. I was experimenting with the functioning and limitation of `cin`.

I wonder how `cin` will take inputs if the user gives incorrect datatypes. So I checked Stack Overflow and got [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15595027/65863):

> When you read an integer and you give it an input of 1.5, what it sees is the integer 1, and it stops at the period since that isn't part of the integer. The ".5" is still in the input. This is the reason that you only get the integer part and it is also the reason why it doesn't seem to wait for input the second time.
>
> To get around this, you could read a float instead of an integer so it reads the whole value, or you could check to see if there is anything else remaining on the line after reading the integer.

So I experimented with it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter 4 numbers: " <<
    std::endl;
    int v1 = 0, v3 = 0;
    float v2 = 0, v4 = 0;
    std::cin >> v1 >> v2 >> v3 >> v4;
    std::cout  << "-> " << v1 << " " << v2 << " " 
    << v3 << " " << v4 << std::endl;    
    return 0;
}
```

```
Enter 4 numbers:
3.14 2.718
-> 3 0.14 2 0.718
```

It works as expected.
But when I tried

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter 3 numbers: " <<
    std::endl;
    int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;
    float v3 = 0;
    std::cin >> v1 >> v2 >> v3;
    std::cout << "-> " << v1 << " " << v2 << " " 
    << v3 << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

```
Enter 3 numbers:
3.14
-> 3 0 0
```

I was expecting `3 0 0.14` because `3` will be `v1` as `int`, `0.14` will be in buffer so when 2nd `>>` encounters it will assign `0` to `v2` and 3rd `>>` assigns `0.14` to `v3` as `v3` is a type `float`.

Please explain the idea how it worked that way.

I used G++ mingw 8.2.0 compiler on my Lenovo Ideapad S340

Comment: When you add links to your post, refer to the original source instead of linking to a photo of the screen.

Comment: This may explain a little further [cin input (input is an int) when I input a letter, instead of printing back incorrect once, …](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50402749/cin-input-input-is-an-int-when-i-input-a-letter-instead-of-printing-back-inco/50403158?r=SearchResults&s=4|26.3422#50403158)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)

Input: `3.14`

You read an integer. `3` is read and `.14` remains in the buffer.

You read another integer. `.` is not a part of integer, therefore nothing is read and [failbit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail) is set.

You read a float. Nothing is read, because failbit is already set.

Answer (score 0):

When std::cin reads in invalid input, std::cin goes into a "fail state". No more can be read in and sometimes fail state results in errors or the spamming of text to the terminal. To exit the fail state you can use the std::cin.clear() function. Also, when you use std::cin.clear() I also recommend using std::cin.ignore(10000,'\n') to clear cin and prevent further failures.